# How to turn off word wrapping in HTML?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I feel silly for not being able to figure this out, but how do I turn off wordwrap? the css `word-wrap` property can be forced on with `break-word`, but cannot be forced *off* (only can be left alone with `normal` value).

How do I force word wrap *off*?

Comment: "I feel silly for not being able to figure this out" gets 587 upvotes and counting.

Comment: for me work white-space: nowrap. white-space: pre is bad show multiple words with mix short and long words.

Comment: I use this so infrequently that I came here to remind myself of the correct answer. There is no shame in forgetting something that you seldom use. This time, I encoded it into a very fine-grained CSS selector that applies just this one attribute for nowrap, probably by far the most common use of the white-space attribute.

Answer (score 1009, accepted):

You need to use the CSS [`white-space`](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-white-space/) attribute.

In particular, `white-space: nowrap` and `white-space: pre` are the most commonly used values. The first one seems to be what you 're after.

Answer (score 32):

Added webkit specific values missing from above

```
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera */
white-space: pre-wrap; /* Chrome */
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE */
```

Answer (score 14):

I wonder why you find as solution the "white-space" with "nowrap" or "pre", it is not doing the correct behaviour: you force your text in a single line!
The text should break lines, but not break words as default. This is caused by some css attributes: word-wrap, overflow-wrap, word-break, and hyphens. So you can have either:

```
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```

So the solution is remove them, or override them with "unset" or "normal":

```
word-break: unset;
word-wrap: unset;
overflow-wrap: unset;
-webkit-hyphens: unset;
-moz-hyphens: unset;
-ms-hyphens: unset;
hyphens: unset;
```

UPDATE: i provide also proof with JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azozp8rr/

Comment: I understand why you want to break on words in general. But to assume there's no valid reason to turn of word wrap doesn't make sense to me. I quickly tried testing your "unset" solution, and it still had word wrapping. If you think it should work, please provide a jsfiddle demo'ing it working.

Comment: I don't know why my reply vanished. Again, you can force nowrap, usually people do it for buttons. But i think it is a bad design for responsive reasons, because texts could go outside the container. Anyway, the question was asking about word-wrap:break-word, forced on, and you was asking how to force off. So, i provided the code to do it. The whitespace:nowrap is another thing, and it is not removing breaking words, it is removing breaking whole lines. 
Also i provide comparison of the code with JSfiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/azozp8rr/](https://jsfiddle.net/azozp8rr/)

Answer (score 14):

`white-space: nowrap;`: Will never break text, everything else is the same

`white-space: pre;`: Will never break text, will keep multiple spaces after one another as multiple spaces, will break only explicitly with a newline

Comment: Wrong. `pre` does wrap while also keeping multiple spaces.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me to stop silly work breaks from happening within Chrome textareas

```
word-break: keep-all;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a HTML only solution, we can just use the [`pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag. It defines "preformatted text" which means that it does not format word-wrapping. Here is a quick example to explain:

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #adf;
}
pre {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    font: inherit;
    background: #fda;
}
```

```html
<div>Look at this, this text is very neat, isn't it? But it's not quite what we want, though, is it? This text shouldn't be here! It should be all the way over there! What can we do?</div>
<pre>The pre tag has come to the rescue! Yay! However, we apologise in advance for any horizontal scrollbars that may be caused. If you need support, please raise a support ticket.</pre>
```