# Content of a DIV only horizontal?

Tags: css, html

I have got a div with some content inside it. Now I want to align the elements horizontally. I used `display : inline;`, but now I've got the problem that when an element reaches the width of the div, there is an internal linebreak. So actually I am looking for a css command that all elements are aligned horizontally AND that there won't be the linebreaks inside the div.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn off word wrapping in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652654/how-to-turn-off-word-wrapping-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

on the enclosing `<div>` to prevent any line breaks. See the MDN docu [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space).

Comment: This works, but how can I prevent the elements that overflow to be hidden? overflow: hidden; doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Forlan07 `overflow: hidden` will only work, if the `<div>` is set to a specific `width`. Maybe you can post an example fiddle, so we can help you directly with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `width:100%` on your div.