# Bootstrap 4 table with one column larger than others

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've created a Bootstra4 table with multiple columns. One of them needs to be larger than the others, in order to fit more text. I'd like to set the minimum width of the larger column, and let Bootstrap4 figure out the size of other columns. 
I've been trying different things, but I can't find a way of setting the width of the desired column. Appreciate any hints. Thanks.

Lets assume that column 11 should be larger.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytable').DataTable(
      {
        "lengthMenu": [ [10, 20, 30, -1], [10, 20, 30, "All"] ]
      }
    );
  } );
</script>

<table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>column 1, default size</th>
      <th>column 2, default size</th>
      <th>column 3, default size</th>
      <th>column 4, default size</th>
      <th>column 5, default size</th>
      <th>column 6, default size</th>
      <th>column 7, default size</th>
      <th>column 8, default size</th>
      <th>column 9, default size</th>
      <th>column 10, default size</th>
      <th>column 11, 15% size/th>
      <th>column 12, default size</th>
      <th>column 13, default size</th>
      <th>column 14, default size</th>
      <th>column 15, default size</th>
      <th>column 16, default size</th>
      <th>column 17, default size</th>
      <th>column 18, default size</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>column 1, default size</td>
      <td>column 2, default size</td>
      <td>column 3, default size</td>
      <td>column 4, default size</td>
      <td>column 5, default size</td>
      <td>column 6, default size</td>
      <td>column 7, default size</td>
      <td>column 8, default size</td>
      <td>column 9, default size</td>
      <td>column 10, default size</td>
      <td>column 11, 15% size</td>
      <td>column 12, default size</td>
      <td>column 13, default size</td>
      <td>column 14, default size</td>
      <td>column 15, default size</td>
      <td>column 16, default size</td>
      <td>column 17, default size</td>
      <td>column 18, default size</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Apart from your described problem, you're missmatching `<td>` with `</th>` inside `<tbody>`

Comment: @FabianSchöner. Thanks. I've fixed the example in my text. It was a typo when I wrote the question , but this part of my code is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that works for my case, in [Set min-width in HTML table's <td>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503849/set-min-width-in-html-tables-td):

```
<td style="min-width:100px">
```

Answer (score 1):

If people are still looking for solution. This worked for me

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A correct way of doing this is using flexbox on the table. more info about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

You could also use col-x being x=1,2,3...,12 (column width) on the table columns. More info about this way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924104/bootstrap-4-table-column-sizing?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Hope that solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks for the flexbox info. I needed to keep it simpler now, using <td style="min-width:100px">

Answer (score 0):

Use a `div` in the eleventh `th` cell and set its min-width.

Comment: Thanks. It works for me without a div: <td style="min-width:100px">