# How to have a table with min td that takes up the entire screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a table e.g. 8 number of columns. It works fine on the desktop screen. However, when trying on a smaller screen or trying to reduce the size of the browser, `tds` get divided equally and content gets squeezed.

I want to have the `min-width` of the `td` to be say 200px. How can we achieve this?

I tried

```
table-layout: fixed
td { min-width:200px;  
 }
```

Apparently, min-width on td does not work.
I also tried putting `<td><div style:"min-width:200px"></div></td>`
However, this does not work. td's border and the content in the `div`gets out of placed when doing so.

Is there any idea?
I can use bootstrap 3 as well if that solves the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503849/set-min-width-in-html-tables-td

Comment: As you can see if you visit the link given by @chintuyadavsara `min-width` is supposed to work. Can you please provide a code snippet with HTML and CSS to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`table-layout: fixed` , this attribute (fixed) affects `min-width`. When I set it to  `automatic` or `inherit`, and add the style `min-width:200px`, the td's width will not change when the width of browser's window is shrinked.