# Pandas col_space (to_html) parameter does not work correctly

Tags: python, html, pandas, html-table

I'm generating this html code from a dataframe, like the one in the example, but the `col_space` parameter, from the `to_html` function, isn't being applied in the final code.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'calorias':[200, 350, 550], 'gordura (%)':[0, 6, 15]}, index=['banana', 'prato feito', 'big mac'])
```

| comida | calorias | gordura (%) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| banana | 200 | 0 |
| prato feito | 350 | 6 |
| big mac | 550 | 15 |

```py
df.to_html(classes='table table-striped', border=0, index=False, justify='left', col_space="100px")
```

```html
<table border="0" class="dataframe table table-striped">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: left;">\n      <th style="min-width: 100px;">calorias</th>\n      <th style="min-width: 100px;">gordura (%)</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <td>200</td>\n      <td>0</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <td>350</td>\n      <td>6</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <td>550</td>\n      <td>15</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>'
```

Comment: I don't understand. It outputs a `"min-width: 100px"`. Isn't it what the parameter is supposed to do?

Comment: Agree with @gmolnar according to the  [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) `col_space` is  _The minimum width of each column in CSS length units._ which should be and is translated into `min-width: 100px;` see -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/18503849/4413446

Comment: That was it! I was able to see the HTML better and it's working now.