# How to make text of a label fit within its width

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have a label in html document, it has a fixed width but when the text exceeds the label's width it goes to 2nd line, I want to the text to fit in given width, no matter if it doesn't show the starting text..
Here is the code

```
<div style="width:50%">
    <label id="mlbl" style="width:50%;">text</label>
</div>
<button id="mbtn">click</button>
```

Script:

```
$('#mbtn').click(function() {
  $('#mlbl').text('asdasda gfgfg ad ad asd ad asd asd ad ad ');
});
```

Here is the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rd79bpwn/

Comment: Change `lable` to `label`. It isn't the solution but a tag called `lable` doesn't exist :)

Comment: Use of `label` ins’t useful either here, unless the attribute `for="mbtn"` is added to associate it with the control.

Comment: What does “no matter if it dont show the starting text” mean? That the *start* of the content should be omitted if the content does not fit on one line? And should be content be just truncated (even within a word, or within a letter)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn off word wrapping in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652654/how-to-turn-off-word-wrapping-in-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding:

```
label{
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You can get the desire effect and also adding three dots to avoid cutting the text abruptly by adding the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` attribute.
Note: `text-overflow`only works in one line texts (Not multiple line).

[TEST](http://jsfiddle.net/rd79bpwn/3/)

**UPDATE:**

So you want to always show the end part of the text no matter what and the initial part that overflows should be hidden. Like this?

[TEST](http://jsfiddle.net/rd79bpwn/6/)

Comment: this skips the end text, i want starting text to skip when text in label overflows. is it possible ?

Comment: If it's still relevant I updated the answer with what you want. It's possible to do, what it's not posibble is to add the three dots at the start when the text overflows via css.

Comment: no need for three dots ... Thanks, u made my morning better by helping me :)

Answer (score 6):

Then simple use `white-space: nowrap`:

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rd79bpwn/2/)

Take a look here [white-space-prop](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop)

Comment: this skips the end text, i want starting text to skip when text in label overflows. is it possible ?

Comment: Hmm not sure what you mean :S

Comment: like if the label contains "hello how are you?" after wrapping it shows "...are you?"

Comment: Can't see this issue. Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate that problem?

Comment: Really can't see an issue here. I can see entire text.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 #mlbl
              {
                overflow : hidden;
                width : 100%;
              }
```