# How can I format this div without the text inside breaking a line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this html code

```html
<h2>
  <div style="display:flex">
  <div>
    Section III :
  </div>
  <div>
    Very long parangrapgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
  </div>
  </div>
</h2>
```

The space inside the first div makes a new line,
Can any body suggest how to attain this format ? I dont to have anything below the Section III, 
I dont want to use  tho and I dont want to adjust width padding etc, is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Add the css property "white-space: nowrap" on the "div".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off word wrapping in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652654/how-to-turn-off-word-wrapping-in-html)

Comment: Yes , unfortunately I dont know the term to search while having this problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the text breaks into multiple lines, which makes it look odd. I added the `white-space: nowrap` styling. You may also want to add some spacing between the two divs.

```html
<h2>
  <div style="display:flex; white-space: nowrap;">
    <div>
      Section III :
    </div>
    <div>
      Very long parangrapgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
    </div>
  </div>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

try `white-space:nowrap` css from the `div` tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply `display:flex` to outer div and `display: inline-block` to inner divs

```css
.myClass {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}

.outerDiv {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="myClass">
      Section III :
    </div>
    <div class="myClass">
      Very long parangrapgggggggggggg
    </div>
  </div>
</h2>
```